# Trying Jenkins and TestRail integration With agiletestware pangolin but not sure where to find the pangolin server

Tags: jenkins, testrail

https://www.agiletestware.com/docs/pangolin-docs/en/latest/setup/server-installation/

Please help me where can i find the pangolin installation file.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this link to download Pangolin installer:
https://www.agiletestware.com/pangolin#download

You also need to register to get free 2-week evaluation license using the link below: 
https://www.agiletestware.com/pangolin/pangolin_register